# AppFabric-ReadThrough implementation how to get the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am trying to use AppFabric for fasten my image retrieval from SQL Database. I created my provider file and load it to my cache. However, I am struggling right now.

How can I call get function from cache using my provider file or do I need to use my provider file while retrieving data?

When I call .Get(key.Key), do I need to see the data coming from my database?

My Read method from provider is as follows, is this correct?

```
public override DataCacheItem Read(DataCacheItemKey key)
    {       
        try
        {
            Object retrievedValue = null;
            DataCacheItem cacheItem;

            retrievedValue = *Running SQL Query Retrieving Image from DB*;//Is that a correct approach? 

            if (retrievedValue == null)
                cacheItem = null;
            else
                cacheItem = DataCacheItemFactory.GetCacheItem(key, cacheName, retrievedValue, null);
            return cacheItem;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's when you get the image.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Stuard. If item is not in the cache, how is AppFabric is writing the requested item into the cache?

Comment: When you pass it to `DataCacheItemFactory.GetCacheItem`

Comment: Ohh I didn't know it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Example:>

using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SampleProvider
{
  public class Provider : DataCacheStoreProvider
  {
    private readonly String dataCacheName;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> config;

    public Provider(string cacheName, Dictionary<string, string> config)
    {
      this.dataCacheName = cacheName; //Store the cache name for future use
      this.config = config;
    }

    public override DataCacheItem Read(DataCacheItemKey key)
    {
      Object retrievedValue = null;
      DataCacheItem cacheItem;

      retrievedValue = ReadFromDatabase(key.Key); //Your implemented method that searches in the backend store based

      if (retrievedValue == null)
        cacheItem = null;
      else
        cacheItem = DataCacheItemFactory.GetCacheItem(key, dataCacheName, retrievedValue, null);
      return cacheItem;
    }
    public override void Read(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<DataCacheItemKey> keys, IDictionary<DataCacheItemKey, DataCacheItem> items)
    {
      foreach (var key in keys)
      {
        items[key] = Read(key);
      }
    }

    public override void Delete(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<DataCacheItemKey> keys) { }

    public override void Delete(DataCacheItemKey key) { }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { }

    public override void Write(IDictionary<DataCacheItemKey, DataCacheItem> items) { }

    public override void Write(DataCacheItem item) { }


    private string ReadFromDatabase(string key)
    {
      string value = string.Empty;
      object retrievedValue = null;
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(config["DBConnection"]))
      {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select Value from KeyValueStore where [Key] = '{0}'", key);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        retrievedValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (retrievedValue != null)
        {
          value = retrievedValue.ToString();
        }
      }

      return value;
    }
  }
}
```